# Is there a way to receive the return value in Python through the OUT parameter in C++?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes, out-parameters

I have a C++ dll, one of the export function is defined as follows:

```
OPERATEMYSQLSTDCALL_API  int __stdcall CheckMac(char * pcMac, OUT  LPSTR errorInfo);
```

I use it in python, use the ctypes  library,i read some of the information and call it as follws:

```
from ctypes import *
lib = WinDLL('OperateMysqlStdcall.dll')
CheckMac = lib.CheckMac
CheckMac.argtypes = [c_char_p, POINTER(c_wchar_p)]
CheckMac.restype = c_int
p1=c_wchar_p()
value = CheckMac('88888888',byref(p1));
print  p1.value
```

but when i execute it，it return None,i'm sure the value "OUT  LPSTR errorInfo" in C++ is not NULL,i print it in console and it shows Correctly.could anyone tells me why it can't work in python.Thank U very much!

Comment: this link may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python

Answer (score 2):

The type of `LPSTR` is `char*` so you should use `c_char_p` for its type as well.  As an output parameter, though, you need a writable string buffer.  Ideally, the API should indicate the size of the buffer passed so a buffer overrun could be checked.

Here's some test DLL code:

```
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
int __stdcall CheckMac(char* pcMac, LPSTR errorInfo)
{
    strcpy(errorInfo, pcMac);
    return 1;
}
```

And Python:

```
from ctypes import *
lib = WinDLL('test.dll')
CheckMac = lib.CheckMac
CheckMac.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_char_p]
CheckMac.restype = c_int
errorInfo = create_string_buffer(1024)
value = CheckMac('88888888',errorInfo);
print errorInfo.value
```

Output:

```
88888888
```

Comment: Thank U very much ,your answer is VERY help for me!